# why $request Doesn't add or remove in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-request

...
When I make add or remove on `Request` it doesn't make any thing, although it works in such other places .
I'm using

```
$request->request->add(['item'=>value]);
```

and using

```
$request->request->remove(['item']);
```

Comment: Are you sure `$request` is really a Request ? what does `dd($request);` output

Comment: yes it is the regular Request class `Illuminate\Http\Request`  but there a small issue on implementing it in laravel itself.
larvel uses `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`.
`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` uses a class that store request data `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag`
the symphony request put its data into the "ParameterBag"
all its data , then the laravel "Request" make override on it by adding the GET data separately so if you have both "GET" and "POST" data will be overridden